# Javascript Algorithm Practice Removing Negatives From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around this one :/

- (Removing Negatives) Given an array X of multiple values (e.g. [-3,5,1,3,2,10]), write a program that removes any negative values in the array.  Once your program is done X should be composed of just positive numbers.  **Do this without creating a temporary array and only using pop method to remove any values in the array.**

My thought was to write a loop through the array.  If X[i] is negative, start another loop swapping X[j] and X[j+1] until the end of the array. (to preserve the order of the array) then use pop().

When I run the script it looks like the loop is infinite.  Also it looks like if there are two negative values in a row the second one may get skipped in the next iteration of i.  Is there a simpler way?

```
var X = [1,-6,-7,8,9];
//test= [1,-7,8,-6,9]
temp = 0

for (i = 0;i<X.length-1;i++){
    if (X[i]<0){
        for (j = i;j<=X.length-1;j++){
            X[j] = temp
            X[j] = X[j+1] 
            X[j+1] = temp
        }
        if(X[X.length-1] < 0){X.pop()}
    }
};
console.log(X);
```

Comment: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: You mention preserving the order of the array, but why?  The description doesn't say anything about preserving order.

Comment: Are you allowed to you `Array.splice` ?

Comment: You are infinite looping because you have `X[j+1] = temp` inside your `j` loop.  When `j` is equal to `X.length - 1`, this line will add an additional entry into the array, causing it to loop again, again adding and looping and adding... forever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very similar to your mentioned approach, except there's no reason to maintain order (unless that is missing from the description).  Loop **in reverse** and when a negative is found, swap it with the last element and pop.  If we first pop all negatives off of the end, we know the last element is not negative.

```js
var x = [1, -6, -7, 8, 9, -3];

// strip all negatives off the end
while (x.length && x[x.length - 1] < 0) {
  x.pop();
}

for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (x[i] < 0) {
    // replace this element with the last element (guaranteed to be positive)
    x[i] = x[x.length - 1];
    x.pop();
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

This solution has linear complexity as it only iterates the list once.

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution. [Compairing Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x9ko9zn/)

Answer (score 5):

Sort the array first so the negative numbers are at the end.
We can sort with a callback that moves the negative numbers to the end.

Then iterate backwards and remove the last indices with `pop` as long as they are negative.

What we're left with is the positive values.

```js
var X = [-3, 5, 3, 8, 1,-6,-7,8,9];

X.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b - a;
});

for (var i=X.length; i--;) {
    if ( X[i] < 0 ) X.pop();
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(X, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Could also be an (almost) one-liner with `filter()`, i.e. `x.filter(function(el) { if (el < 0) { return false; } return true; });`

Comment: Wouldn't filter return a new array, I assumed the point was to alter the array in place without creating a temporary one ?

Comment: @jdphenix `filter` creates a new array.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - maybe, this was the best I could think of, and when using `pop` the values to pop has to be at the end, one can't pop in the midddle ?

Comment: Indeed, good call there. I wonder why the requirement to not create a temporary array is there then. It seems like a backwards requirement for a JavaScript program, when it has built in functionality (i.e. `filter()`) that does *nearly what they need*

Comment: @adeneo Since OP is learning JS I think you should explain what you're doing here `for (var i=X.length; i--;)` It's confusing.

Comment: @Jonathan - I did explain it - *"then iterate backwards ..."*

Comment: The for loop is unclear I'd say, write it like this: `var i = X.length; while (i--) {...}`?

Comment: @adeneo I posted a solution that I think is working and linear time.  You are correct that you can't pop in the middle, but you can swap your element to the end and then pop.  (or really just replace the middle element with the last and then pop).

Comment: @adeneo your code is broken somehow, though I'm not sure why: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zn586bqc/)

Comment: It's the sort function, I changed it back to what it was initially, which doesn't preserve order. I'm sure there's a way to just move the negative values and leave the rest, but I'll leave it like this.

Answer (score 3):

There are many good answers already. Here's a straightforward filter that doesn't sort the array and uses an auxiliary array index `j <= i`:

```
function removeNeg(arr) {
    var j = 0;

    // filter array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) arr[j++] = arr[i];
    }

    // pop excess elements
    while (j < arr.length) arr.pop();
}
```

This is really the C programmer's approach to James Montagne's answer, which is neater, because it pops as you go.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = [1, -6, -7, 8, 9];
var i = 0;
while (i < x.length) {
    if (x[i] < 0) {
        x[i] = x[x.length - 1];
        x.pop();
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

just pop, no other methods of Array used

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution that doesn't require sorting. For every element, shift it, push it if it is not negative. Do this a number of times equivalent to the array size. This can either be done with shift/push or pop/unshift.

```
var origLen = X.length;

for(var i = 0; i < origLen; i++) {
  var val = X.pop();

  if(val > 0)
     X.unshift(val);
}
```

Comment: But now you're using `shift` to remove from the array, not `pop`